# geth client - cannot keep it in sync

Tags: go-ethereum

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 instance on Amazon EC2

I can do:

```
geth console 2>> ~/geth.log
instance: Geth/v1.4.3-stable/linux/go1.6.1
>
```

Everything looks fine:

```
> eth.blockNumber
546120

> net.peerCount
13
```

OK. Great. The blockNumber ticks up as expected.

Now, I'd like to be able to logout and go away and get on with things.

I am using `screen`

I do `Ctrl+A` followed by `D`. I can tail `~/geth.log` and I can see the blockNumber incrementing.

I logout. However, when I tail the `geth.log` file several hours later, it keeps getting stuck:

`I0513 05:53:21.227568 eth/downloader/downloader.go:274] Synchronisation failed: no peers to keep download active`

The Amazon firewall is wide open. I have `ufw` running on my instance. It allows port 80, 22 and 443 (IPv4 and IPv6).

I have no idea what's going on. I have spent hours at this.

Comment: The geth client listens on TCP port 30303 and you'll also need UDP port 30301 for peer discovery. Try explicitly forwarding those and see if it helps.

Comment: You could also monitor the connections themselves using `netstat -atn` (TCP) and `netstat -aun` (UDP), and see if/when they drop off.

Comment: Thanks Richard, good suggestions. I'll try this and report back

Comment: just disable `ufw` and try.

Comment: @niksmac Still can't get it to work. Even with suggestions from. I suspect, and I might be wrong, that all the peers I'm connecting to are in Amazon (test nodes fired up to play with Ethereum) and contain bad blocks. Hence I keep getting stuck?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions sofar. I ran `geth --maxPeers=300` last night. I saw around 298/299/300 peers connected when I ran `net.numPeers`, however the block number was refusing to increment! Are all the peers not agreeing? Are they bad peers? What is going on?

Comment: I even tried a larger EC2 instance (small). Thought more memory might improve matters. I saw a lot of virtual memory swapping. I ended up deleting the files in `chaindata` folder restarting the whole thing with the `--fast` option: `geth --fast console 2>> ~/geth.log`